# Setting background image in canvas (fabric js)

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

**Goal** is to set up a canvas on top of an image.  (Making product mockup generator like teespring has, but simpler)

**Codepen**: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YmEGyW

I have gotten this almost to where I would like it but I have a few issues:

If I set the background image on the canvas, I am unable to save (not sure why but when i do this i can't click "save", nothing happens).  Like so:

```
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('fCanvas', {
  backgroundImage: "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B3ubyt3iIvkaUlpHVEpDTGhjQzg",
...
});
```

To fix this, I create a canvas on a canvas... But this only works when I upload an image (or how i figured out how to make it work, so far, like in the **codepen** example)

**What I would like is** to have a background image pre loaded instead of needing to upload a background image.

**How** can I have the google drive image loaded on load (down below) without needing to upload through the input/form?

In practice, this will dynamically but for now I would like to use `"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B3ubyt3iIvkaUlpHVEpDTGhjQzg"` for the background image.  Then be able to upload the scalable image on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use css for setting background image.

**Solution #1**

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.0.0-beta.7/fabric.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <canvas id="fCanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
<a id="downloadLnk" download="YourFileName.jpg">Download as image</a>
```

**JS**

```
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('fCanvas');
fabric.Image.fromURL('https://picsum.photos/id/1083/200/300', 
    function(img) {
        canvas.setBackgroundImage(img, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
          scaleX: canvas.width / img.width,
          scaleY: canvas.height / img.height
        });
    }, { crossOrigin: 'Anonymous' });

function download() {
   var dt = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
   this.href = dt;
};
downloadLnk.addEventListener('click', download, false);
```

Codepen

https://codepen.io/murli2308/pen/XvzzWz

**Solution #2**

**CSS**

```
canvas {
    background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1083/200/300);
}
```

You can replace CSS selector with class or id. Also, you can add background-size and background-position according to your requirement.

Comment: But then I can't save it.  I need to save the mockup to the database.  I have this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JgOKYa as a previous attempt but i cannot figure out how to save the background image along with the canvas

Comment: Updated answer added with JS

Comment: I tried that but nothing changed.  Can you show it in the codepen?

Comment: Now the issue arises with using the `canvas.setBackgroundImage`.. I am now no longer able to save the canvas for reasons i cannot seem to find

Comment: by setting cross origin it will. Updated answer and codepen as well

Comment: Is there a reason why `"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B3ubyt3iIvkaUlpHVEpDTGhjQzg"` doesn'nt work as the image background? Not sure why but when i use that link it doesn't show the image

Comment: Not sure. Reasons might be like - Does it require login? is this public image?

Comment: It's a public image.  It's the one in the codepen in the comments i linked.  Idk, not much of a big deal though.  I had it working on an earlier pen so probably something I'm overlooking as of rn.  thanks for the help!

Comment: setting the background will work when the options args are supplied, it the better approach  in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

looking at the docs [here](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-1#images) the options which made it work for me are not shown.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas-id');

canvas.setBackgroundImage('https://......', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
    backgroundImageOpacity: 1,
    backgroundImageStretch: false
});
```